# Apache 1.3 security vulnerabilities

Tags: apache, security

Now that Apache 1.3 has been end-of-lifed for a while, security vulnerabilities aren't being patched. Is there a list of known unpatched security vulnerabilities in Apache 1.3? I would like this list to convince a potential client to migrate. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With version 1.3.42 being the last release in the 1.3 branch, there seem to be some known vulnerabilities that this version is vulnerable to. One of those is listed on [Apache’s own vulnerabilities list](http://web.archive.org/web/20140814124530/http://httpd.apache.org/security/vulnerabilities_13.html). Others can be found in vulnerability databases using the [CPE](http://nvd.nist.gov/cpe.cfm) key `cpe:/a:apache:http_server:1.3.42`, e.g., via [National Vulnerability Database](http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/search-results?adv_search=true&cpe=cpe%3a%2fa%3aapache%3ahttp_server%3a1.3.42) or [CVE Details](http://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-45/product_id-66/version_id-109441/Apache-Http-Server-1.3.42.html).